# What is the winged creature on the back of the Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes book?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, books, content-identification, art

On the back of the *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* book, there is a small creature with wings:

[image]

What is this creature? It doesn't match any of the creatures in any of the monster manuals. It kind of looks like an [imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp), but it clearly isn't one, and my only other guess is that maybe it's some kind of [homunculus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/homunculus)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## It appears to be a Berbalang

[image: coverart]

Looking through the pictures in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes it most looks like the [Berbalang](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof/bestiary#Berbalang).

Wizards of the coast has been known to put [baby pictures of monsters in their books](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148006/which-creature-is-depicted-in-this-xanathars-guide-illustration-of-a-war-mage).

As such I suspect it's a baby Berbalang. For reference a Berbalang looks like this:

[image: berbalang]

Comment: Whilst i agree with you that this is the most likely candidate, I would like to point out several difference, notably the colouration, the shape of the nose and the shape of the mouth are all different. This may simply be due to differing art styles though, the variant cover version looks more like the Berbalang in the book.

Comment: @LiamMorris If you check out the linked question. The baby ki-rin depicted is quite different to that depicted in Volo's Guide to Monsters (https://media-waterdeep.cursecdn.com/avatars/thumbnails/9/709/253/315/636330514467564552.jpeg). I would put it down to precisely that, different art styles etc. Monsters in the book only depict an average specimin. Additionally there are many animals in our world that change colouring between youth and adult (the swan being the most notable).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a Homunculus.

Since it has wings, it's not a quasit. As it doesn't have a tail with a stinger, it's not an imp. It could possibly be some kind of mephit, but it doesn't have any clear elemental appearance.

This leaves homunculus as the most likely tiny gargoyle-looking creature.

Answer (score 1):

### As far as I can tell, it's not in the books

[image: Impossible, perhaps the archives are incomplete]

After scanning through *Volo’s Guide to Monsters*, *The Monster Manual*, *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes*, *The Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide*, *Guild Masters’ Guide to Ravnica* and *Wayfinder’s Guide to Ebberon*, I can safely say that specific creature is not in any of those books.

However, there is one other place that creature is found - it's on the back of the *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* variant:

[image: MToF variant cover barcode]

---

### Perhaps it is a Berbalang

Comparing the image on the variant back cover of *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* to the image provided by illustro, I believe that this is a Berbalang:

[image: Berbalang]

If the creature on the back of the variant cover is indeed a Berbalang, we may assume that the one on the standard cover is also a Berbalang, though in a different art style. Similar things have been done before, compare the beholder on the standard cover to Xanathar’s Guide to Everything to the one on the variant cover:

[image: XGtE variant cover comparison]

Answer (score -3):

It's acting like a gremlin. Berbalangs don't seem to have any interest in breaking things. Gremlin batspawn is the right color, shape, proportion and would be likely to be doing what that little guy is doing.

Comment: Berblangs have interest in finding out knowledge, and spying on Mordenkainen or helping him seems like an excellent way of obtaining knowledge.